# Pascal unhandles exception occured

Tags: pascal

When I run this procedure

```
procedure displaydir;
var count:integer;
    directoryfile: file of tdir;
    directory:array [1..100] of tdir;

begin
     assignfile(directoryfile, 'directory.bin');
     reset(directoryfile);
     count:=0;
     repeat
     read(directoryfile,directory[count]);
     writeln('Name: ',directory[count].name);
     writeln('Telephone number: ',directory[count].tel);
     writeln('Job title: ',directory[count].jobtitle);
     writeln;
     writeln;
     count:=count+1;
     until (directory[count-1].name = 'q');


end;
```

I get the error

An unhandled exception occurred at $00000000:
EAccessViolation: Access violation
  $00000000
  $2A005640
  $B6F83F97

Unfortunately I couldn't find a solution on the internet, help is much appreciated!

Comment: I don't know what Pascal compiler you're using, but you should turn on any of the aggressive run-time checks, such as [array range checking](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/prog/progsu65.html). It will do you good until you get your sea legs. And with programs like this, the bit of performance penalty isn't going to matter.

Answer (score 1):

You've declared an array directory as 1..100, but set count to 0 on first run through.  directory[ 0] is out of range.  You're probably trying to write to read only memory.